# Error after MAMP to Live WP

Tags: wordpress, error-handling

hi i get these errors after getting live with my wordpress site from local to server.

Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'bones_register_sidebars' not found or invalid function name in /is/htdocs/wp1108989_5IDG6XP7VR/www/cgi-bin/website/wp-includes/plugin.php on line 403

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /is/htdocs/wp1108989_5IDG6XP7VR/www/cgi-bin/website/wp-includes/plugin.php:403) in /is/htdocs/wp1108989_5IDG6XP7VR/www/cgi-bin/website/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 881

hoster is hosteurope. 
any one any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what those errors are, but if everything works as expected then add a php value to your `.htaccess` file

```
php_value error_reporting 0
```

Comment: Try setting defineing your wordpress site url in your wp-config mate.

Comment: sorry. thats the problem. i can not show the url, because its an customer project. i used the BONES WP Boilerplate. i think it must be a problem in the theme files. but i can not find any. it works perfect locally with MAMP.

Comment: You might want to contact your host then!